# How do I get a newly created ID from the Order Controller to the Order Item Controller in laravel

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, controller

What I want to do is pass a newly created auto increment OrderID from my Order Controller Create Form to the OrderItem Controller Create Form, and add Order_Items related to that specific OrderID.

I want to create iditems when I create an order which `order_id` is auto-incremented in database.

My store code in ordercontroller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    project::create($input);
    $g = project::orderBy('order_id', 'desc')->first();
    $id= new items;
    $id->order_id = $g;
    $id->save();
    items::create($input);
    
    return redirect('/project')->with('insert','f');
}
```

item model code

```
class items extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'invoice_order_item';
    protected $primaryKey = 'order_item_id';
    protected $fillable = [ 'order_id' , 'item_code', 'item_name', 'order_item_quantity', 'order_item_price', 'order_item_final_amount'];
}
```

order model code

```
class project extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'invoice_order';
    protected $primaryKey = 'order_id';
    protected $fillable = ['order_receiver_name', 'order_receiver_address', 'order_total_before_tax', 'order_total_tax',
     'order_tax_per', 'order_total_after_tax', 'order_amount_paid', 'order_total_amount_due', 'note'];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Model::create()` returns the newly created Database Model, **including its primary key**. All you need to do is assign `project::create()` to a variable, and reference it later:

```
$project = project::create($input);
...
$items = new items();
$items->order_id = $project->order_id;
$items->save();

// items::create($input); // Drop this line; you already created an `items` model via `new items(); ... $items->save()`
```

That being said, there's a lot of issues with your code...

1. Why would you name the Model representation of your `invoice_order` table  `project`? That should be `InvoiceOrder`, to A) match the table name and B) meet Laravel naming conventions
2. Why would `order_id` be the Primary Key for the `invoice_order` table? It's typical to use `id`, or `invoice_order_id` as the Primary. `order_id` is *close*, but just a little off.
3. You can use relationships to create these too:

```
$project = project::create($input);
$items = $project->items()->create($input);
```

You would need to define the relationship between them though, which can be done by reading the documentation:

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships

Corrected Code:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
  $inputs = $request->input()
  $invoiceOrder = InvoiceOrder::create($inputs);
  $invoiceOrderItem = $invoiceOrder->invoiceOrderItems()->create($inputs);
}
```

`app\Models\InvoiceOrder.php`:

```
class InvoiceOrder extends Model {
  protected $table = 'invoice_order';
  protected $primaryKey = 'order_id';
  protected $fillable = [
    'order_receiver_name',
    'order_receiver_address',
    'order_total_before_tax',
    'order_total_tax',
    'order_tax_per',
    'order_total_after_tax',
    'order_amount_paid',
    'order_total_amount_due',
    'note'
  ];

  public function invoiceOrderItems() {
    return $this->hasMany(InvoiceOrderItem::class);
  }
}
```

`app\Models\InvoiceOrderItem.php`:

```
class InvoiceOrderItem extends Model {
  protected $table = 'invoice_order_item';
  protected $primaryKey = 'order_item_id';
  protected $fillable = [
    'order_id',
    'item_code',
    'item_name',
    'order_item_quantity',
    'order_item_price',
    'order_item_final_amount'
  ];

  public function invoiceOrder() {
    return $this->belongsTo(InvoiceOrder::class);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the createMany method to create multiple related models:

```
$order = Order::create($request->all());

$orderItems = $order->orderItems()->createMany([
    ['amount' => 55.50],
    ['amount' => 99.20],
]);
```